# jQuery element outerWidth() returns 0

Tags: jquery, width, outerwidth

I have a image element with css set

```
height: 64px;
width: auto;
```

When i try to get height and width through jQuery using `.outerHeight()` & `.outerWidth()`, i can get height correctly but width returns as 0. I have even tried width(), innerWidth() still same.

I have to set the image dynamically. Maybe that is having some issue. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abdulpathan/0vrbnpe3/3

Could someone help me to tackle this.

Thanks

Comment: The properties you've mentioned work absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/qm4xp3rv/. It would help to have a complete example of the problem behaviour showing your HTML, JS and all other relevant CSS

Comment: ^^ e.g., a [mcve]. Some reasons this happens: The browser hasn't rendered the element yet, the element isn't in the DOM yet, the element is hidden, ...

Comment: I have to set the image dynamically. Maybe that is having some issue. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/abdulpathan/0vrbnpe3/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to simply get the width once the image has loaded.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').on("load", function() {
  
  var height = $('#test').outerHeight();
  var width = $('#test').outerWidth();
  width = width.toFixed(2); // rounds it
  console.log('Width:' + width);
  console.log('Height:' + height);
  })
  $('#test').attr('src', 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.png'); 
});
```

```css
.test-img {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <img id="test" class="test-img">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i dont think that there was need of all such calculations, `$('#test').outerWidth();` work perfectly in `load()`. Because when the image is loaded completely you have all the measurements needed correctly.

Comment: @AbdulPathan You're right! I changed the code accordingly and it's much simpler now :)